# Arbitrary File Upload Vulnerability

Tags: python, nginx, directory-traversal, file-inclusion

I have found an arbitrary file upload vulnerability on a flask application that I was playing with that essentially allows me to append to any file (and create new ones) in the file system. The code that causes the vulnerability boils down to:

```
with open(user_controlled, "a+") as f:
        f.write(also_user_controlled)
```

I was trying to turn that into remote code execution but I haven't been able to do it since the usual technique of uploading of a PHP shell does not work for this case (as I'm dealing with flask). Can anyone think of a way?

Possibly important details:

- the server is running on linux;
- nginx is being used to serve the application.

Comment: As Flask is a Python application, you need to send a Python webshell.

Comment: That would work but I have no way of restarting the flask server. So any shell I upload will not be loaded (I have already tried).

Comment: So overwrite an existing Python file that the server already can reliably be triggered to invoke code in? Or just drop your own SSH key in some user's .ssh/authorized_keys file and SSH in, if the SSH server is internet-exposed (many are).

Comment: Can you write anywhere on the file system?

Comment: It's a CTF like challenge on a VM, so the code for the web app is very small (only a couple files). Since the flask webapp is not reloaded there are no python files that I can modify and then invoke.

Comment: Writing to the authorized_keys file worked! Thanks for the suggestion!